# Missing tag after docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I am researching the new [docker stack deploy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/) command in addition to the new [docker compose v3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) and it seems like `docker stack deploy` could almost replace `docker-compose up -d`.

One different I found is quite odd, and that is the running container shows the image name but not the tag.

### Inspect Compose Up

This is a snipped of running inspect on a container created via `docker-compose up -d`.

```
{
    Command: "node server.js",
    Image: "styfle/notification-service:v1.0.0"
}
```

### Inspect Stack Deploy

This is a snipped of running inspect on a container created via `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml --with-registry-auth=true tst`.

```
{
    Command: "node server.js",
    Image: "styfle/notification-service@sha256:827e6a274c5ee2b941dde402f82069c2da644927cac53c0b2cd5acacb739f949"
}
```

Why is tag (in this case, the suffix `:v1.0.0`) missing from the `Image` and can it be found somewhere else? I'm using Docker CE 17.03.1-ce-win5 (10743).

Answer (score 1):

Docker services use image pinning to ensure every node in the swarm is running the same image. If a tag is replaced, or in a different state on different nodes, the sha256 digest will ensure that only the v1.0.0 version that you had when creating the service is the one used. For more details, see [docker's documentation on the subject](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#specify-the-image-version-the-service-should-use).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems like this might be a [bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31574) because the sha256 digest is necessary but the tag name should still be there before the hash, right?

Comment: Nope, the digest replaces the tag, the tag can change, the digest is fixed.

Comment: So the second part of my question is can the tag be retrieved somewhere else?

Comment: I can't think of a reliable solution. You can get the list of repo tags for that image reference, but there can be multiple tags, and they can change after you submit it so that no tags at all currently point to it: `docker inspect -f '{{.RepoTags}}' $image`